# Javascript: passing data down classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have a class `Third`, that requires a token in its constructor to create it.

```
import Third from './Third.js'

export class Second {
    
   private _instanceOThird = new Third(_token)

   constructor(
      _token: string
   ) {} 
}
```

---

```
import Second from './Second.js'

export class First {
    
   init() {
       const _instanceOfSecond = new Second('MyToken');
   }
}
```

The issue is that the token from `Second` comes from yet another class, called `First`.  Class `Second` doesn't use the token but just needs it so that `Third` can be created within it.
Is this an anti-pattern of passing around data?

Comment: No, it's not. It's perfectly fine

Comment: What problem does your code so far give you? Can you create a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run to demonstrate that problem? Also it's hard say if something is an anti-pattern from such a contrived example. How you pass around a token is based on how that token is expected to be fetched and used.

Comment: This would be fine, if you made it actually work by putting `this._instanceOThird = new Third(_token)` inside the `constructor` or `Second` where the `_token` parameter is in scope.

Comment: Depending on what you actually do, it might be cleaner if the `Second` class constructor would take just a token, but an entire `Third` instance.